# Cache page displaying as error message?

Tags: magento2

For some reason my cache page displays as an error message.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Backend::system/cache/additional.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'cache.additional'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Backend::system/cache/additional.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'cache.additional'
#0 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#3 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#4 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('cache.additiona...')
#5 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cache.additiona...')
#6 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cache.additiona...')
#7 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#8 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#9 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content')
#10 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col')
#11 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#12 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col')
#13 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col...')
#14 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#15 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col...')
#16 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...')
#17 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#18 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...')
#19 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content')
#20 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#21 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content')
#22 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#23 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#24 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#25 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page')
#26 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#27 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page')
#28 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#29 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#30 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#31 /home/momentst/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#32 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#33 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#34 /home/momentst/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#35 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#36 /home/momentst/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#37 /home/momentst/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#38 {main}
```

Comment: Add more details that cause this error.

Comment: I have exact the same problem. Anybody out there who knows what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the folder `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/system/cache/` was missing. Take it from an archive from magento.com that has the same version of Magento 2 with your store.